# org-latex-classes for headings

Tags: org-mode, latex

Given this class code:

```
(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
              '("report"
                "\\documentclass{report}"
                ("\\chapter{%s}" . "\\chapter*{%s}")
                ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
                ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
                ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}"))
              )
```

When writing my orgmode article, do I need to specify for each heading the type of class it is supposed to be?

Comment: The LaTeX class is specified *per document*, not *per heading*.

Comment: what I want to know is whether subheadings will follow the formatting specified. Meaning, a sub-sub-sub heading will be formatted as subsection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `report` class in your question, level-1 headings will become chapters, level-2 headings will become sections, level-3 headings will become subsections, level-4 headings will become subsubsections, higher level headings will become items - that is, *assuming that the H options setting (`org-export-headline-levels`) is higher than or equal to 4*. If it is lower than 4, then headings will become items sooner: e.g. if H is 3, there will be no subsubsections: they will be turned to items instead.

You can set the H value per-file:

```
#+OPTIONS: H:4
```

or by setting the corresponding variable:

```el
(setq org-export-headline-levels 4)
```

Its value is 3 by default.

Comment: Thank you! Very clear. I suppose that having #+OPTIONS: H:10 does not hurt just to make sure all headings are formatted if we decide to later on add formatting specific to headings > 4.